# Move data based on value (CSV) - Python / Excel

Tags: python, excel

[image]I'm in the process of writing some code which generates my timesheets for work automatically.

The code pulls the dates I worked from Apple iCalendar so I have a list of days I worked in a month e.g.

2019-07-06

2019-07-07

2019-07-08

2019-07-09

At the moment a CSV is created with the date starting at row 1 and iterating through the rows 2, 3, 4 etc...

Is there a way to populate the CSV so that in the example above, the first 5 rows would be empty, and then row 6 is the first row to be populated (because the first day worked was 2019-07-06)?

I've tried creating a separate CSV which simply generates 31 rows (days of the month). Is there a way to combine the two CSV's?

Ultimately I need the days of the month worked to populate my timesheet with a "1" if I worked that day.

Code below:

```
with open('Days Worked.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, lineterminator='\n')
for day_number in range(total_days):
    days_worked = (start_date + dt.timedelta(days = day_number)).date()
    days_list = [days_worked]
    writer.writerow(days_list)
```

Comment: I'm going to strongly encourage you to try pandas (https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) and maybe even expand into https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/ (iirc you might need xlrd and other stuff to make xlsxwriter work properly)

Comment: Hi Mauve, I am using Pandas but can't think of a way to only populate the days worked on the timesheet.

I agree adding this list of days worked to a DataFrame is sensible, but would appreciate some help in transferring this method to the timesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be refined, but this should get you started:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Day'] = ['' for i in range(1,33)]
dates = ['2019-07-06', '2019-07-07', '2019-07-08', '2019-07-09']

for date in dates:
    day = int(date[-2:])
    df['Day'][day] = date

df = df[1:]
df.to_csv(filename_here.csv)
```

You can also get into [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)